# Problem with the position of the view of RootController inside of a SplitView

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I changed my rootView controller of my split view to add one UIimage and an UIView. All works fine but when I navigate in portrait mode and change to landscape mode my view is a few pixels down than it have to stay. If I navigate in landscape mode it doesn't occur. And the most strange is if I navigate in portrait and I push the popover button and then I change the orientation, the view of the root is in the perfect place :S.

Is like the popover put it in the correct place.

Could you help me please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve the problem: When I dismiss the popover I have to get out the animation. If I do this, all works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all places where you manually set property `frame` of your views that are not correctly displayed.
2. Check property `autoresizingMask` of your all view.

If problem wasn't found place your code here.

Comment: Well I check all the frames and all it is ok. And put the code is a little complicated because there a lot of lines... I will review all tomorrow one more time. Thank you very much.